# What webkit animations are available in Zepto.js

Tags: javascript

I'm investigating Zepto.js for a mobile project but not finding much documentation on the .anim action. I know it is webkit specific but which parts of the webkit animation css does it work with? For example, 3d transforms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto) you can see, that it uses `-webkit-transform` internally, so everything that is available with it can be used.

**translate3d**

```
$('div').anim({ translate3d: '10px, 20px, 30px'}, 2, 'ease-out');
```

**Zepto.Fx**

```
(function($){
  $.fn.anim = function(props, dur, ease){
    var transforms = [], opacity, k;
    for (k in props) 
        k === 'opacity' ? opacity=props[k] : transforms.push(k+'('+props[k]+')');
    return this.css({ '-webkit-transition': 'all '+(dur||0.5)+'s '+(ease||''),
      '-webkit-transform': transforms.join(' '), opacity: opacity });
  }
})(Zepto);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Zepto also supports the following [CSS transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-functions) properties:
>
> - `translate(X|Y|Z|3d)`
> - `rotate(X|Y|Z|3d)`
> - `scale(X|Y|Z)`
> - `matrix(3d)`
> - `perspective`
> - `skew(X|Y)`

(http://zeptojs.com/#animate)

They seem to be [prefixed like this](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/fx.js#L7):

```
vendors = { Webkit: 'webkit', Moz: '', O: 'o', ms: 'MS' },
```